# HTML tags not working when using append in a java script but html code works fine when doing hardcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem that I am not able to solve since few days.... The problem is that when I hardcode HTML tags with values the page is getting loaded with no issues....but while try to load data dynamically by parsing rss feed and then using append to insert the data in the main tag it's not working....  I tried tracing the output of the java script by using alert fucntioin and the output is the extact html that is required...

My code was working fine until I added

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script>
```

I am also calling jquery 1.10.2 at bottom of the page referring to lots of other js

The code is as below:

```
<div id="grid">
        <script>
        myFunction('test');
        </script>   

                </div>
```

Fucntion:

```
function myFunction(var1) {

        $('html').removeClass('no-js');
    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.webkit) {
            $('grid').addClass('webkit');
        }

        $('#grid').facebook_wall({
            id: var1,
            access_token: '193673707489176|55a9bc60f1b35074263ea95e45218fc3',
            limit: 1

        });



};
</script>
```

Please help I am not able to trace it....

Comment: use `$('#grid').addClass('webkit');` not  `$('grid').addClass('webkit');`

Comment: Tried that but no luck.... :(  ..it seems like if the page is already fully load than the code that is appended afterwards is not getting executed....

Comment: What is doing `facebook_wall` method???

Comment: It parse data from my facebook rss feeds using json and pass it to my HTML..... I just check and found that if I pass data with "<div>" tag without any class it is working fine but when is include class to it it is not working....

Comment: no it is using .append to pass value ...

Answer (score -1):

Don't need semi colon after function myFunction (){ }

Comment: Not answer (and hardly useful even as a comment).